# Is it safe to call CloseHandle (handle) who handle is NULL

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

Delete a NULL pointer is secure.

```
int* p = NULL;
delete p;         // ok, secure
```

What ist about Handles?

```
HANDLE h = NULL;
CloseHandle(h);   // allowed?
```

I am reading [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx) but still not sure. It say something about ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE but it is 6L, not NULL.

I come from a destructor of a class, which gives me a C6387 warning [Error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ea2fc4d-ffc3-4c3c-bfae-d42aa56235d8(VS.110).aspx)

```
if (m_hThread)
    WaitForSingleObject(m_hThread, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(m_hThread);    // warninig C6387
m_hThread = NULL;
```

Comment: why you not move `CloseHandle(m_hThread);` into `if (m_hThread)` block as `WaitForSingleObject` ?

Comment: Some APIs use `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, some APIs use `NULL` instead. Which API are you using to get the `HANDLE`?   `CreateThread()`? It uses `NULL`.  MSDN does not specify what happens if you pass an invalid handle to `CloseHandle()`, so don't rely on it.

Answer (score 12):

No.  You may not call `CloseHandle` on a NULL handle.  Look at the documentation for the argument.  It says:

> *hObject* [in] A valid handle to an open object.

NULL is not a handle to an open object.

The fact that you get C6387 is precisely because you are passing a "possibly-null" handle to `CloseHandle`.

You must write the code as:

```
if (m_hThread) {
    WaitForSingleObject(m_hThread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(m_hThread);
}
```

(There is no point setting m_hThread to NULL after this - it is going to cease to exist in a very short while).

Comment: Yes I understand this warning. But I assume (secure) functions like CloseHandle() checks already the parameter against NULL.

Comment: @TomTom Yes, the function will simply fail if you pass invalid handle value, if compiler issues a warning for such usage, it is not assumed to be a common usage patern.

Comment: @TomTom You are violating the API contract, which says you have to pass a valid handle. `NULL` is not a valid handle. It even says that an exception is thrown in debug mode. If the API contract is that clear, there is no reason to program based on assumptions. If you want to safe some typing, just create a one-liner: `inline BOOL CloseHandleSafe(HANDLE h){ return h && h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ? CloseHandle(h) : TRUE;}` which you can call without checking first.

Comment: @zett42 Good idea, but this oneliner is not secure if we call it accidently twice. After CloseHandle() it is necessary to set the `Handle h = NULL or h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

Comment: @TomTomt : it's  safe because you call it in a dtor, and dtors aren't called twice

Comment: @MSalters : I think the OP was referring to the proposed `CloseHandleSafe` not to me eliding the `=NULL`.

Comment: @MSalters; No not safe, in the class there are functions that starts and end the thread too.

Comment: @TomTom Do you mean "there are other functions that currently call `CloseHandle`?  (If so, they need to ensure `m_hThread` is NULL afterwards) or do you mean "there are other functions that may access `m_hThread` after the destructor is called" - if so, you are invoking undefined behaviour and *nothing* you do is safe.

Comment: There is one piece of documentation, that's often overlooked: The [SAL annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/sal-annotations) on the `hObject` parameter. This parameter is marked as `_In_` (as opposed to `_In_opt_`), so passing a `nullptr` is not allowed. It's the SAL annotation that causes the compiler to issue the [C6387](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c6387) warning.

Comment: @zett42, in practice NT doesn't raise an exception for a `NULL` handle, either with a debugger attached or with the global system flags configured to do so always. Closing a `NULL` handle only causes the call to fail and incurs the expense of a system call. In practice it is safe without requiring an SEH/VEH handler. Though obviously it's not recommended to ignore the warning, since the documentation doesn't explicitly say that closing a `NULL` handle is as much a no-op as 'closing' a pseudo-handle such as `GetCurrentProcess()` (i.e. same as `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, in practice).

Comment: @zett42 I am a big fan for one-liner, can you add code to set the handle to NULL. My best essay is a 3 liner :(

Comment: @TomTom I can't do shorter than 3 liner: `inline BOOL CloseHandleSafe(HANDLE& h){ HANDLE tmp = h; h = NULL; return tmp && tmp != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ? CloseHandle(tmp) : TRUE; }`. But I would not use this function, better is RAII wrapper that calls `CloseHandle` in destructor.